# How to compute regression coefficients with proc mixed in sas?

Tags: sas, linear-regression

Here are [my data](http://www.megafileupload.com/eSdb/test.txt). Data are structured like so: `id x1 x2 x3 y`.

I used `proc mixed` to analyze it, but now want to determine regression coefficients and I don't know how to do it. I'm only a beginner with `sas`. From the results I see that `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `x1x2x3` are the significant effects, but how to determine the coefficients `alpha, beta, gamma, delta, theta`:

`y = theta + alpha*x1  + beta*x2 + gamma*x3 + delta*x1*x2*x3`

This is my code:

```
ods graphics on;
proc mixed data=test;
  class x1 x2 x3;
  model y = x1 | x2 | x3 / solution residual;
  random id;
run;
ods graphics off;
```

EDIT 1: Here is a part of the table `Solutions for Fixed Effects`:

[image: Solutions for Fixed Effects]

Since `x1` has two levels, there are two rows for it in the table. Do I get the effect of `x1` by summing these two values: `-109.07` for the first row and `0` for the second, or should I do something else? Note that this is `2^k` design. The effect of `x1` should be computed as half the difference between the average values for `y` when `x1` is high (20) and when it is low (10).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your model, `x1`, `x2`, `x3` should be treated as continuous variables, then you should be able to get the coefficients in your model.

```
proc mixed data=test;
model y=x1 x2 x3 x1*x2*x3/ solution residual;
random id/s;
run;
```

However, based on your code and the values of `x1`, `x2` and `x3`, it would be better to treat them as categorical variable as what you did, then the Estimate in your table actually is the mean difference between whatever two levels. The link below may help you understand your results.
http://support.sas.com/kb/38/384.html[explanation of estimation of coefficients](http://support.sas.com/kb/38/384.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was looking for this for half an hour in the sas help and online documentation until I found this.

Answer (score 0):

The `solution` option should generate your estimates.You need to include it on the `model` and `random` statements. You should see two tables, **Solution for Fixed Effects** and **Solution for Random Effects** that hold the estimates.

```
proc mixed data=test;
class x1 x2 x3;
model y = x1 | x2 | x3 / solution residual;
random id / s;
run;
```

The Random Coefficients example in the documentation is close to your question.

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect034.htm

Comment: Dear Reeza, please see the edit. I clarified the question a bit.